# Как центрировать блоки (div)?

Tags: html, css

Как центрировать несколько одинаковых, идущих подряд блоков (div)?

Если пишем им `float:left`, тогда они выравниваются по левому краю, если не писать, будут отображаться в столбик.

Comment: [Выравнивание по центру](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/technogrette/html/align-center/)

Comment: Это не работает, блоки отображаются вертикально, а нужно горизонтально.

Comment: Опять не то, вопрос внимательнее читайте. Сделал с использованием таблицы вместо внешнего контейнера, а чисто дивами такое чувство что это сделать нельзя.

Comment: К кому относятся эти комментарии?

Comment: `display: inline-block;` - блоки будут вести себя так же, как и изображения.

Answer (score 5):

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}

div div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Пример.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bumbay/bE67R/)

Comment: это не работает

Comment: А как же пример?

Answer (score 1):

Пример от exec работает. Только там еще прописать надо в каждом блоке float:left, также в основном блоке див (корневом) надо тоже указать:

```
display: inline-block; 
text-align:center;
```

Нужно все это дело обвернуть в еще один див и указать `text-align:center;`. Корневых получится два блока и потом уже идут блоки с флоатами.

тут видимо принцип получается такой, что самый первый див с флоатом цыпляется к ближайшему диву и не дает ему ровняться по макету сайта. А вот еще один див корневой самый первый уже не связан с флоатами и ровняется нормально.

Comment: `inline-block` будет оставлять горизонтальные отсупы между блоками. и ни `padding`, ни `margin` не спасут. а если добавлять блоку `float`, то зачем ему `inline`?

Answer (score 1):

Пример с `float: left`:

```css
.row {
  width: 300px;
  clear: both;
}

.row > div {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте с

```
position: absolute;
```

Каждый блок отдельно перетаскивать.

Comment: Блоков неизвестное количество, формируется скриптом